# XYToLine and Error 999999

Tags: arcgis-desktop, error-999999

When attempting to convert this text file to lines using the [XYToLine](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/xy-to-line.htm) tool I keep getting the generic [ERROR 999999](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error-999999). What is going on?

```
ID  SrcX        SrcY        DstX        DstY
1   905653.9545 728436.4238 905130.0745 727809.7597 
2   914841.5615 724105.0236 914777.3853 723706.6229 
3   865711.6414 722514      865431.546  722264.887  
4   861556.3599 724077.2146 860963.8363 723713.0272
```

Result:

```
Executing: XYToLine test_line.txt X:\Env-dat.082\default.gdb\links_from_txt SrcX SrcY DstX DstY GEODESIC ID "GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119522E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision"
Start Time: Thu Sep 03 14:58:32 2015
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (XYToLine).
Failed at Thu Sep 03 14:58:33 2015 (Elapsed Time: 1.42 seconds)
```

Comment: 722514 probably needs a decimal 722514.0000 to be consistent arcmap is fussy...

Comment: Right track @Mapperz but not quite there. Dropping decimal was okay (for this tool), but then adding a tab to keep columns lined up was not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the error means "trouble parsing input file". There are actually 3 problems here. I'm not sure if the 99 problem would have cropped up with any single one or whether it requires a constellation.

**Mix and match white space delimiters**. Rows were using tabs while the header which was added manually used spaces (in Notepad++ hit the "show all characters" toolbar button, ¶).

[image: text file screen shot]

**Fixed width delimited.** The program which generated this text file left out implied digits, so `1273629` instead of `1273629.0000`, however it then added an extra tab to keep the columns line up. Nothing wrong with this, it's standard practice in fixed-width delimited files, however XYToLines doesn't know about those.

[image: double tab as single delimiter]

*Completely wrong coordinate system!* `905653.9545 728436.4238 905130.0745 727809.7597` are clearly not geographic or decimal degrees numbers which can't be higher or lower than `180.0` and `-180.0`.  I should have seen this immediately but was distracted by the other errors. (This problem doesn't generate an error message, just the wrong result of zero-length lines).

.

UPDATE: In follow up testing, it turns out that

- Header line is optional. If left out XYToLine shows "Field1, Field2, ..."
- Only one thing to fix in order to avoid error, it is sufficient to search and replace double-tab with single (`\t\t` with `\t`).

.

*What a sad state of affairs, "Error: 999999" happens so often it has it's own tag! Anyway, this took me a couple of hours and two days to solve, so I figure it's worth adding to the noisy heap.*